# Bootstrap 3 in Umbraco

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, umbraco, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I implement the new Bootstrap 3 in Umbraco? 
Just created a new Umbraco site and I want it to be based on the new Bootstrap 3. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You have to build all of the code yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no starter kit, or package for it.  But it shouldn't be too tough

Create your new Umbraco site first, just a bare bones site, no themes, no kits, no packages(yet)

Download the new bootstrap files and add the bootstrap img folder and css files to your StyleSheets folder, add the bootstrap.min.js to your Scripts folder.

Make a new master/global template that references all of your bootstrap dependencies

Make all other templates use this new template as their master.

[image]

Hope this helps get you going.